# Enabling chained method using ".delay"

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to realize this method-chain style:

```
var foo = function(){};

foo.prototype = {
 say : function(s){
        alert(s);
        return this;
       },
 delay : function(ms){
          var _this = this;
          setTimeout(function(){
           return _this;
          }, ms);
         return this; // If I omit this, there will be an error.
         }
}

var bar = new foo();
bar.delay(2000).say('hello'); // this will immediately alert 'hello'.
```

I want to use like this:

```
bar.delay(2000).say('hello'); // in 2 sec. say 'hello'.
```

not like this:

```
bar.delay(2000, function()...); // it's not a chained method
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible but you can't do it by simply returning from the `delay()` function after `ms` - calls to setTimeout are asynchronous and so return immediately. To achieve this effect you must implement your own queuing system. Some code:

```
var queue = new Queue();

function delay(ms) {
    queue.enqueue("delay");
    setTimeout(function() {
        popQueue(true);
    }, ms);

    return this;
}

function say(s) {
    queue.enqueue(function() {
        alert(s);
    });
    popQueue();

    return this;
}

function popQueue(removeDelay) {
    if (removeDelay) {
        if (queue.peek() == "delay") queue.dequeue();
    }
    while (!queue.isEmpty() && queue.peek() != "delay") {
        (queue.dequeue())();
    }
}
```

In essence, the code works by modifying every function that is "delayable", so that it inserts itself into a queue, rather than executing immediately. The `delay()` function inserts a string into the queue as a "blocking" item, that prevents functions added to the queue from executing. You can then use a timeout to remove the block from the queue after the given number of milliseconds.

The above code just gives you an idea of how delaying can be implemented but isn't a working example. Obviously you'd need some sort of [Queue implementation](http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/queues/), or you can modify it to use arrays, or you can implement your own `SelfExecutingQueue` object to automatically continue to execute functions (until it hits a non-function object) immediately after queuing or dequeuing without requiring you to manually call `popQueue()`, etc...

Comment: Thank you! I see this concept. So it seems that I need a big modification to my original code using kinda "wrapper" function like queue. [Queue implementation] link looks very interesting. I will read later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to advice, I made it! Here is the code.

```
var foo = function(){};

foo.prototype = {
 say : function(s){
  Queue.enqueue(function(){
   alert(s);
  });
  Queue.flush();
  return this;
 },
 delay : function(ms){
  Queue.enqueue('delay:' + ms);
  return this;
 }
}

Queue = {
 entries : [],
 inprocess : null,
 enqueue : function(entry){
  Queue.entries.push(entry);
 },
 flush : function(){
  if(Queue.inprocess) return;
  while (Queue.entries.length){
   var entry = Queue.entries.shift();
   if(entry.toString().indexOf('delay:') !== -1){
    var ms = Number(entry.split(':')[1]);
    Queue.inprocess = setTimeout(function(){
     Queue.inprocess = null;
     Queue.flush();
    }, ms);
    return;
   }
   entry();
  }
 }
}
```

I prepared a Queue object to manage functions' entries.
With this, I can play with a method-chain:

```
var bar = new foo();
bar.delay(2000).say('Hello, ').delay(3000).say('world!');
```

Many thanks!